# Can I export Datadog dashboards via Datadog REST API?

Tags: export, backup, datadog

Is it possible to export or download Datadog dashboards via Datadog REST API?

Export and update of Datadog Monitors works fine. I need the same functionality for dashboards.

Comment: If REST API is not a hard requirement and you just need some script to automate the export, you could give this tool a try: https://github.com/ouyi/dashjson (I am the author).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Still yes.

Docs for new Dashboard endpoint [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=bash#dashboards).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Yes.

Docs for screenboards [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#screenboards).

Docs for timeboards [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#timeboards).

Comment: There is now a Dashboards API endpoint replacing the endpoints for screenboards and timeboards - see the [new API docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=ruby#dashboards).

Comment: Thanks RichVel! I've updated the answer to reflect this new endpoint. Good catch.

Comment: The new Dashboard link is dead now.  Here is a new link. https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/dashboards/#get-a-dashboard